# remove columns/adjust model in API MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I built a simple API to get some data I use in javascript code on a different page. I'm a bit new to MVC framework, (an inspired convert from ASP.NET forms), so not sure exactly how do I adjust the columns that it spits out. This is my code:

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class GetUserDefaultsAPIController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public GetUserDefaultsAPIController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet] 
        public async Task<ActionResult<MyMVC.Models.UserDefaults>> GetDefaultsAPI()
        {

            int ProfileId = GetSelectedProfileIdfromCookie(); // custom function  
            var UserDefaultsModel = await _context.UserDefaults.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.cId == ProfileId);
            if (UserDefaultsModel == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return UserDefaultsModel ;
        }
```

This code then spits out a nice JSON which I can directly use (based on UserDefaultsModel row with a certain Id). The problem is that it has a few fields that are not necessary (like Id, among some others). At this stage I manually use javascript to delete those, but it would be nice if I could do it first server-side so don't have to do this client side?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is not return your entity class directly. Create a new class containing just the properties you want, map the values from your entity over, and then return that new class, commonly called a view model or DTO.

Comment: Thanks Chris - I get what you mean, but it is just a few columns - including the identifier column which I kind of need for selection, but would prefer to leave it out

Comment: @user3685724 For the separation of concerns and to prevent vulnerabilities associated with the model bindings, I would recommend following Chris' advice.  You will never want to expose your domain models much less entities to the views or outside clients.

Comment: Yes, that separation of concerns becomes increasingly important when you start looking at versioning. If you use the entity class directly, then if you make a change to your entity class(es), then you *immediately* break all clients using the API. If you use a DTO, then you can independently evolve both the database and API, as well as version the API to allow gradual deprecation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information I will learn about the DTOs then, much appreciated!

Comment: But just FYI, I it is apparently also possible to use [JsonIgnore] in the definition of the model above columns to exclude, then it will ignore those when making JSON